# assert_template in test_case.rb seems to be broken. How do I test the layout in a controller spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, controller

Below is a code snippet form #assert_template. expected_layout is not defined! and what sets @layouts.

```
   msg = build_message(message,
            "expecting layout <?> but action rendered <?>",
            expected_layout, @layouts.keys)

    case layout = options[:layout]
    when String
      assert(@layouts.include?(expected_layout), msg)
```

I am trying assert the layout which is dynamically defined in the controller action. The spec says...

```
response.should render_template(:layout => "bare", :partial => "show")
```

I get

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `expected_layout'
```